# Change size of cursor "hittest" bounding area in WPF

Tags: wpf, cursor

Is it possible to increase the size of the point that is used for hit testing using the cursor in WPF?

I would like to be able to hit test with something similar to the entire area covered by the cursors image, as opposed to just a single point.

Im doing some line drawing that I need to recieve mouse events (enter/leave/etc), but having to align the cursor over small strokethicknesses can be tricky, and simply increasing the thickness isnt an option for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One technique you can use here is to draw a second line or path with the same geometry and increased thickness, make it invisible and place it on top of the visible line. To do this set `Stroke=Transparent`, which will be invisible but still pick up mouse events.

This gives you control over the hit test area, admittedly with a little extra work on your part.